# let $x ,y ,z \in \mathbb{N} ,x \leq y\leq z$ and : $\frac{100}{336}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{xyz}$then : $x+y+z =?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let $x ,y ,z \in \mathbb{N} ,x \leq y\leq z$

and :

$$\frac{100}{336}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{xyz}$$

then :

$$x+y+z =?$$

my try :

$$\frac{100}{336}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{xyz}=\frac{xy+z+1}{xyz}=\frac{25}{84}$$

now ?

Comment: typo or mistake the numerator of the last fraction should have $\color{red}{y z}$ not $xy$ ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit . no.

Comment: **Hint.** Multiply the equation by the Least Common Multiplier of $336, x, xy, xyz$:$$100zyx=336zy+336z+336$$Then, Divide by $100zy$, and you get: $$x=\frac{84(zy+z+1)}{25zy}$$

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder . now : what is answer ?

Comment: The numerator of the penultimate fraction should be $yz+z+1$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$ with $x<y<z$. First, you can rewrite the equation as
$$ \dfrac{100}{336}=\dfrac{25\lambda}{84\lambda}=\dfrac{yz+z+1}{xyz}. $$
for a positive integer $\lambda$. Since we know that $xyz$ and that $yz+z+1$ are  integers, we can hope to find a solution for the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}84\lambda=xyz\\
24\lambda=y(z+1)\end{cases}.$$
We then have $y=\tfrac{24\lambda}{z+1}$, which translates to 
$$ 84=\dfrac{24xz}{z+1}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad7(z+1)=2xz.$$
Thus, $7=(2x-7)z$, which suggests the solution $x=4$ and $z=7$. Inputting this in the first equation of the system, we have $3\lambda=y $. If we want to respect our condition $x<y<z$, we find $y=6$.

In conclusion, $x=4$, $y=6$ and $z=7$ is a solution.

*Please note that I have edited this answer because I made a mistake forgetting about the conditions.*

Comment: $x ,y ,z \in \mathbb{N} ,x \leq y\leq z\implies y\nleq x$, thus this solution is invalid

Comment: but $x ,y ,z \in \mathbb{N} ,x \leq y\leq z$

Comment: Thank you, I made some changes.

Comment: why ? $24\lambda=y(z+1)$

Answer (score 2):

It should be $x=4$, $y=6$, $z=7$ and the answer to the original question is 17.

You can use the method [described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion) for obtaining the Engel expansion of a number.

The Engel expansion for $x$ is written $x=\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_1a_2}+\frac{1}{a_1a_2a_3}+\cdots$

As described in the wiki, the non-decreasing values $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ can be obtained using

$$u_1=x
\qquad a_k=\left \lceil \frac{1}{u_k} \right \rceil
\qquad u_{k+1}=u_ka_k-1
$$

and stopping when we reach $u_k = 0$.

Starting with $x=\frac{25}{84}$ leads to the required solution.